# Given a string of digits, return the longest substring with alternating odd/even or even/odd digits

Tags: python

So I was doing this python challenge for fun, but for some reason it is saying I am incorrect and I have no idea why. The challenge prompt said this:
Given a string of digits, return the longest substring with alternating odd/even or even/odd digits. If two or more substrings have the same length, return the substring that occurs first.

Examples

```
longest_substring("225424272163254474441338664823") ➞ "272163254"
# substrings = 254, 272163254, 474, 41, 38, 23

longest_substring("594127169973391692147228678476") ➞ "16921472"
# substrings = 94127, 169, 16921472, 678, 476

longest_substring("721449827599186159274227324466") ➞ "7214"
# substrings = 7214, 498, 27, 18, 61, 9274, 27, 32
# 7214 and 9274 have same length, but 7214 occurs first.
```

Notes
The minimum alternating substring size is 2.

The code I wrote for a solution was this:

```
def longest_substring(digits):
    substring = []
    final = []
    loop = 0 # just loops through the for loop
    start = 0
    loop2 = 0
    while loop+1 < len(digits):
        num = int(digits[loop])
        num2 = int(digits[loop+1])
        if (num + num2)%2 != 0 and start == 0:
            substring.append(num)
            substring.append(num2)
            start += 1
    
        elif (num + num2)%2 != 0:
            substring.append(num2)

        else:
            start = 0
            loop2 += 1
            final.append(substring.copy())
            substring.clear()
        loop += 1
    sorted_list = list(sorted(final, key=len))
    if len(sorted_list[-1]) == len(sorted_list[-2]):
        index1 = final.index(sorted_list[-1])
        index2 = final.index(sorted_list[-2])
        if index1 < index2: # because the larger than not first
            sorted_list = sorted_list[-1]
        else:
            sorted_list = sorted_list[-2]
    sorted_list = str(sorted_list)
    sorted_list = sorted_list.replace('[','')
    sorted_list = sorted_list.replace(']', '')
    sorted_list = sorted_list.replace(', ','')
    return str(sorted_list) # or print(str(sorted_list)) neither works
```

If you're curious the challenge is [here](https://edabit.com/challenge/RB6iWFrCd6rXWH3vi)

Comment: I don't think "debug my program" is an appropriate question.  I assume examples is what you got from the problem, so you need to provide input and the invalid output you are getting.  It would be more motivating for me if you shared what you have tried yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually prefer using a shorter code. It's easier to look for errors IMO.
Does this work for you?

```
def longest_substring(digits):
    max_len = 0
    ans = ''
    for i in range(len(digits)):
        temp = digits[i]
        for x in range(i+1, len(digits)):
            if int(digits[x])%2 != int(digits[x-1])%2:
                temp += digits[x]
            else:
                break
        if len(temp) > max_len:
            max_len = len(temp)
            ans = temp
    return ans
```

Here's something a bit simpler:

```
def longest_substring(digits):
    current = longest = digits[0]
    for digit in digits[1:]:
        if int(digit)%2 != int(current[-1])%2:
            current += digit
        else:
            longest = longest if len(longest) >= len(current) else current
            current = digit
    longest = longest if len(longest) >= len(current) else current
    return longest
```

Answer (score 1):

The bit about how you're picking the indexes at the end doesn't always work, leading to cases where your list ends up with all of the possibilities in it.  If, instead you modify the code to be explicit, and run through the entire list after you create `sorted_list`:

```
    best = []
    for cur in sorted_list:
        if len(cur) > len(best):
            best = cur
    return "".join([str(x) for x in best])
```

The rest of your implementation will work.

And for kicks, I took a pass at simplifying it:

```
def longest_substring(digits):
    possible, best = "", ""
    for x in digits + " ":
        if x == " " or (len(possible) > 0 and int(possible[-1]) % 2 == int(x) % 2):
            best = possible if len(possible) > len(best) else best
            possible = ""
        possible += x
    return best
```